# Can I connect Redis with MongoDb directly?

Tags: mongodb, caching, redis

I am a novice to using Redis. We use MongoDB in our application. I am thinking of implementing an automatic cache where Redis will connect to MongoDb and fills its cache from MongoDB automatically. Is this possible? Is there any connector available for mongo db from Redis?

Answer (score 1):

Implement cache invalidation is hard.

Instead, use a CDC (Change data capture) system. There are many projects available, namely https://debezium.io/. Looks for mongodb connector and redis sink connector for debezium.